# Compute antiderivative of $x \frac{3}{4} \sqrt{ -x}$

Tags: integration

I need to compute the area under $x \times\frac{3}{4} \times \sqrt{|x|}$ from x=-1 to x=1. Therefore I need to compute the antiderivative of $x \times \frac{3}{4} \times \sqrt{x} $ for $0 \le x \le 1$, which is straight forward, $ \frac{3}{10} \times x^{2.5}$. And for $ -1 \le x \le 0 $ I need to compute the antiderivative of $x \frac{3}{4} \sqrt{ -x}$. I am stuck on how to rewrite $x $ and $ \sqrt{ -x}$ as a single term.

Comment: Hint: $x\frac34\sqrt{|x|}$ is an [odd function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions). Equivalently, do the substitution $x \mapsto -y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since $-1<x<0$ on your integral, you can define $u=-x$ and change variables. That way there will no longer be a $-$ sign under the radical.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast and good response. This allowed me to calculate the integral

Comment: @hays Yes, since $|x|$ is a piecewise function, in dealing with it for integrals orr derivativees one often breaks things up and uses a substitution (for integrals) or does separate derivatives. At least that's how I deal with it when possible.

Answer (score 0):

$x\frac34\sqrt{|x|}$ is an odd function - so the integral from -1 to 1 is zero.

Comment: I do see / get that it is equal to zero however, I must show may calculation.